# make a site to fit any screen size?

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on this site which looks ok in the screen resolution of 1280x1024 but when i change the screen resolution to 1280x768 it is absolutely awful.

You can view the site that i'm working on here: http://tinyurl.com/d3xhfdq

I have 4 div's (mainWraper, header, content and footer).

what is proper procedure to follow in order to make the site fit any screen resolution?

what i need to do is to fit everything inside the mainWraper in any screen size?

Thanks

Comment: You really need to learn about responsive design.

Comment: Drop the tables, especially those floating..

Comment: @EdwinAlex, do i? how about the answer? if everyone knew about everything then sites like stackoverflow would've been quite as hell!!!!!

Comment: @MichelleDodson I just suggested a way. Its your wish to take or ignore..

Comment: @MichelleDodson that's the answer. Responsive design.

Comment: #yourdiv{width:100%;} There, it fills the space at every resolution, Just proceed from here

Comment: If you're taking the time to learn about responsive design, you'd like to learn about tableless layouts. Besides being a good practice, it'll help you lots with layout maintenance.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, My div's have 100% width but still do not fill the screen.

Comment: Indeed, I see a lot of fixed width elements, like `950px`, which has a table at 84% (of 950px) inside, which is the central part of your design, and is also left aligned (use `auto` for left and right margin, for example, to center your element)

Comment: @DamienPirsy, oh yes, you are right. so do you reckon i should give 100% width to everything in order to fit the screen size?

Comment: Using percentage, or `em`s, could be a start. Fixed width are ok, of course, it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsive design is the topic you should research. [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/) has a [great collection of articles](http://alistapart.com/topic/responsive-design) pertaining to just this topic. I recommend you read the following articles in the following order:

1. [Fluid Grids](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids)
2. [Responsive Web Design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)
3. [Fluid Images](http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images)

These three will get you well on your way to designing responsively. In addition, don't forget the viewport `meta` tag that *php NoOb* suggested. It makes a real difference when you're on a physical device (some emulators seem to ignore it). Additional information on this particular tag can be found at the links below:

- [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers - Mobile | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)
- [Quick Tip: Don’t Forget the Viewport Meta Tag | Webdesigntuts+](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using [Media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), don't forget to use also

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

The above code (if you will) was developed by apple, and is gaining momentum as it makes apple iphones, and tablets render a pages made for desktops.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 media queries. Generally you would specify a min or max-width to define your design, but you could use  height as well.

For instance, you could write a media query that would execute a certain piece of CSS when the height of the window is 768px or more, and a different piece of CSS when the window is less than 768px:

```
   @media screen and (min-height: 768px) {
    #mainWraper {
      /* your code here */
    }
  }


   @media screen and (min-height: 0px) {
      #mainWraper {
        /* your code here */
      }
   }
```

You can also call media queries in the head of your html like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 960px)" href="myStylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: That would most of the time just duplicate the code, and will make mainteinace a hell.